# React - how to write logic/service class that will be accessed inside of smart component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am coming from Angular, where I used dependency injection, but how to decouple here in React, that would be suitable easily for unit testing later? I feel like having instances with new() is huge anti pattern, because it introduces coupling, but on other side static methods can be tested?

I am using smart-dumb component pattern. I also want to separate huge logic classes from smart component into own classes(aka services).

Which one is correct way to create those classes which then will be called inside of smart component?

Option 1:

```
export default class AuthValidation {

    // id_token C7: The current time MUST be before the time represented by the exp Claim (possibly allowing for some small leeway to account for clock skew).
    public IsTokenExpired(token: string, offsetSeconds?: number): boolean {

        let decoded: any;
        decoded = this.GetPayloadFromToken(token, false);

        let tokenExpirationDate = this.getTokenExpirationDate(decoded);
        offsetSeconds = offsetSeconds || 0;

        if (tokenExpirationDate == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Token expired?
        return !(tokenExpirationDate.valueOf() > (new Date().valueOf() + (offsetSeconds * 1000)));
    }
}
```

then access inside of smart component like:

```
AuthValidation auth = new AuthValidation();
```

or Option 2:

```
export class AuthValidation {
    // id_token C7: The current time MUST be before the time represented by the exp Claim (possibly allowing for some small leeway to account for clock skew).
    static IsTokenExpired(token: string, offsetSeconds?: number): boolean {

        let decoded: any;
        decoded = this.GetPayloadFromToken(token, false);

        let tokenExpirationDate = this.getTokenExpirationDate(decoded);
        offsetSeconds = offsetSeconds || 0;

        if (tokenExpirationDate == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Token expired?
        return !(tokenExpirationDate.valueOf() > (new Date().valueOf() + (offsetSeconds * 1000)));
    }
}
```

Access inside of component:

```
AuthValidation.IsTokenExpired(...);
```

I have 10 methods inside of authentication, and I don't want to put it in smart component container, it looks too crowded, or is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it. You say that you want to inject it in order to replace it during testing.

The react way to inject stuff is to supply it as a prop.

If you want a dependency injection style way of working you could use a context to provide these instances. Read more about those here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

You would then need to wrap your component with a `Consumer` that supplies the instance.

To ease the pain of doing it manually you could create a higher order component that uses some form of convention. Read more about these here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

To cut down on boilerplate you could use decorators using something like babel ([stage 2](https://bocoup.com/blog/javascript-developers-watch-your-language), so use with caution). I can imagine this looking something like this:

```
@inject('authValidation')
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
```

The `inject` higher order component would use a `Consumer` to grab the correct instance from the context and supply it as the `authValidation` prop to the `MyComponent`. At the root of your tree you need a `Provider` that stores the instance into the context.

Note that this only makes sense if you are actually using it in a lot of places.

A completely different route is just importing the dependency and using some sort of plugin for your build system that supplies a different version during testing. Dependency injection causes a lot of indirection making it harder to understand and find the code that actually runs. As you can tell this makes debugging and learning (for new team members) harder.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but I was looking without injecting actually, pure react way

Comment: What do you mean? There is only two options: 1. pass in a prop 2. don't pass in a prop. I described both. For the props version I gave you different ways of removing boilerplate. For the non-props version it doesn't really matter what you do, static functions, bag of functions, singleton, global, the choice there is one of taste. Pick one that feels right, it's easily switched to something else when you change your mind.